# Search for subnet with name containg "lb-private-subnet-ca-central-1a"

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to get the subnet with the name that contain "lb-private-subnet-ca-central-1a". I'm using the count parameter is set to 1 for subnets with the name "lb", and 0 for subnets without the name and "for" to get subnet (it least this is what is try) but when i run the code i'm getting

```
│ Error: Missing item separator
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/pplus-aws-vpc/pplus-aws-vpc/locals.tf line 45, in locals:
│   45: lb_private_subnets = [local.private_subnets[i], for i in range(length(local.private_subnets)) if local.private_subnets[i].count == 1]
│ 
│ Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next item.
```

The locals code

```
locals {
  az_names = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.zones.names, 0, var.az_count)
  private_subnets_no = var.az_count * length(var.private_subnet_name_list)
  public_subnets_no = var.az_count * length(var.public_subnet_name_list)

  private_subnets = flatten(
    [for name_index, name in var.private_subnet_name_list :
      [
        for az_index, az in local.az_names :
        {
          name = name
          az   = az
          cidr_block = cidrsubnet(
            var.vpc_cidr,
            var.subnet_new_mask_bits,
            (name_index * var.az_count + az_index + local.private_subnets_no)
          )
          tags = try(var.private_subnet_tags[name][az], {})
          count = contains(name, "lb-private-subnet-ca-central-1a") ? 1 : 0
        }
      ]
    ]
  )

  public_subnets = flatten(
    [for name_index, name in var.public_subnet_name_list :
      [
        for az_index, az in local.az_names :
        {
          name = name
          az   = az
          cidr_block = cidrsubnet(
            var.vpc_cidr,
            var.subnet_new_mask_bits,
            (name_index * var.az_count + az_index)
          )
        }
      ]
    ]
  )

lb_private_subnets = [local.private_subnets[i], for i in range(length(local.private_subnets)) if local.private_subnets[i].count == 1]
}
```

Thank you

I'm trying to filter all subnets with name containing "lb-private-subnet-ca-central-1a". which will be used in the same vpc module that creates the subnets.

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "blackhole" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.vpc,
    aws_subnet.private_subnets
  ]

  /* subnet_id       = local.filtered_private_subnets[0].id */
  subnet_id        = local.lb_private_subnets
  security_groups = [aws_vpc.vpc.default_security_group_id]
  tags            = var.common_tags
}



resource "aws_route" "vpc_main_rt_blackhole" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.vpc, 
    aws_network_interface.blackhole
  ]

  route_table_id = aws_vpc.vpc.main_route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/8"  
  network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.blackhole.id

}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here, but those are definitely syntax errors. Best guess is you need to resolve via `[for i in length(local.private_subnets) : local.private_subnets[i] if i % 2 == 1]`, but there are many resolutions to the syntax errors depending upon what you are trying to achieve.